# What kind of specialist would be competent in the behavioural nuances of a certain dog breed?

Tags: dogs, behavior

I am seeking a specialist competent in how dogs of a certain breed usually behave: questions are around what those dogs are likely to do in certain circumstances, how they react to certain stimulus etc. This specialist would be my expert witness in a court proceeding where answers to those questions matter.

In what kind of places specialists like that can be found?

One obvious option is breeders. What are other options? Is there a branch of science studying this so that I could perhaps try universities? is there an academic degree about it? Something else like that?

Comment: Welcome to Pets! What breed is the dog in question? And what did the dog do? If it's not one of the typical [fighting breeds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_dog_fighting_breeds), you'll have a *very hard* time finding an expert who can reliably prove that a certain breed X would react with an action Y in a situation Z. That mostly depends on upbringing, socialization and training. Breeds do predispose dogs to certain behaviors, but they do not define the dog.

Comment: @Elmy Black Labrador retrievers (which are usually used for duck hunting) attacking domestic ducks. Will they do so upon giving chance vs do they need to be encouraged?

Comment: They're retrievers ... they retrieve..